# Не работает DataTable

Tags: angular5, datatable

Скачал:

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install datatables.net --save
npm install datatables.net-dt --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
npm install @types/datatables.net --save-dev
```

В angular.json подключил:

```
...
"styles": [
    "src/styles.less",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "node_modules/datatables.net-dt/css/jquery.dataTables.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "node_modules/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"
],
...
```

Использую:

html:

`... <table #table class="mb-0 border-bottom table table-striped table-sm">...`

ts:

```
@ViewChild('table') table;
  dataTable: any;
ngOnInit():void{
   this.dataTable = $(this.table.nativeElement);
   this.dataTable.DataTable();
}
```

Вижу ошибуку:

```
TypeError: this.dataTable.DataTable is not a function
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал (не помогло):

```
npm rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clear
npm install
```

Comment: Попробуйте импортировать DataTablesModule в app.module

Comment: @Pantera если написать `$('.table').DataTable();` тоже получаю ошибку. Удалил `import * as $ from 'jquery';` и все заработало

Comment: @Pantera я так понимаю что ошибка была в том, что несколько раз импортировал `jQuery`